# Posts are not displaying on their category and tag page

Tags: posts, categories, archives

I created a post and assigned it a category and tag also. The post is displaying on the main post page. But the problem is **when I go to the specific category page the post is not showing.**

For information,
I am using the theme "Smarty 3.3" to build a website for a school.
My post URL looks like "http://localhost/myschool/2019/12/22/post-name".
And the category URL is like "http://localhost/myschool/category/news/"

I must add, the post is not even showing when search by category or tag name.

Comment: Welcome to the community. But I'm afraid, we're not the developer of a specific plugin/theme. What we all have in common is WordPress core. When asking for assistance, it's always best to add some [debug info](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info), instead of stating only the symptoms. When you are ready, please feel free to [edit] your question and add some more context for someone to assist you from distance. :)

Comment: Go to the editing mode of the post and recheck is the post has a category assigned to it or not.

Comment: I have checked this multiple times.

Comment: Flush your permalinks (just visiting Settings -> Permalinks will achieve this).